# SQL statement with Anorm gives me an other result than in PostgreSQL CLI

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework-2.2, anorm

I want to check if something is present in my database before saving it in order to avoid `key duplicate errors`. I'm using `Play! 2.2.6` with `anorm` and `Postgresql 9.3`.

So I wrote a little function (I omit the errors check):

```
def testIfExist(fieldName: String, value: String): Boolean = {
  DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    SQL( """SELECT exists(SELECT 1 FROM events where {fieldName}={value} LIMIT 1)""")
      .on(
        'fieldName -> fieldName,
        'value -> value
      ).execute()
  }
}
```

**But it always return `true`** although my database is totally empty.

So I tested to replace

`SELECT exists(SELECT 1 FROM events where {fieldName}={value} LIMIT 1`

by

`SELECT exists(SELECT 1 FROM events where name='aname' LIMIT 1`

and it still always return `true`...

I also tested the same query directly in `psql` and the response is what I except : `false`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`execute` returns `true` if *anything* was returned in the result set. In this case it will be `0` or `1`. It will only return `false` if the query was an update (returns no result set). You need to use `as` with a `ResultSetParser` to parse the results.

There's another problem with this code as well. You can't supply column names in prepared statements. `{fieldName}={value}`. This will get turned into a string comparison, which will probably always be false. Instead, you can use string interpolation to insert the field name into the query. Though be wary, `fieldName` should be be from user defined input as it is vulnerable to SQL injection. (Your users shouldn't need know about your columns anyway)

```
SQL(s"SELECT exists(SELECT 1 FROM events where ${fieldName} = {value} LIMIT 1)")
   .on("value" -> value)
   .as(scalar[Boolean].single)
```